# nodejs error 404 on post (not via url)

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever i try to submit from the index i get an error.
im trying to get the values from the username and password inputs.

this should be the code to handle the post:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var username=req.body.username;
  var password=req.body.password;
  res.render("the username and password you posted:" +password+username);
  });
```

my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var patienten = require('./routes/patienten');
var form = require('./routes/form');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/patienten', patienten);
app.use('/form', form);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("i am from /get");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendfile("/");
});
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var username=req.body.username;
  var password=req.body.password;
  res.render("the username and password you posted:" +password+username);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

The form.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');
var request = require('request');
var ejs = require('querystring');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/form', function(req, res) {
    res.render('form', {
        title: 'EPD - Login',
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The form.ejs (the submit page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  action="/" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="gogo">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use [`res.render()`](http://www.expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) for regular responses back to the client. Use `res.send()` instead. This is why you are receiving your error. `res.render()` is for use with a view engine in Express and sends back the rendered view template to the client. IE `ejs` in this case is the defined view engine and thats what the below code is doing

```
// view engine setup
// Tells express to render from the views directory
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Your `404` handler should be your 2nd to last route in your express main file as it is a catch all for ***any routes that didn't match your defined routes*** since Express goes through routes Top-Down. Along with your 404 handler being defined in the wrong location within your Express app, you should examine possible collisions with your routes.

You have the following Router Middleware

`app.use('/', routes);`

and then subsequently the following GET route

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("i am from /get");
});
```

Depending on the contents of your `routes` file there could be collisions and the `app.get()` will never be executed.

You should set your routes up as follows:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/patienten', patienten);
app.use('/form', form);

// If you have a GET inside your 'routes' file
// from above, then this may never get called if 
// it also contains a route for GET '/'
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log('I am from get');
  return res.render('index');
});


// My comment from above about your GET '/' would
// also apply to this POST route 
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var username=req.body.username;
  var password=req.body.password;
  return res.status(200).send("the username and password you posted: " + password + ' ' + username);
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  return next(err);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    return res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  return res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
```

You'll also need to change your `HTTP Method` specified in your `form.ejs` file from `GET` to `POST`

`<form action="/" method="POST">`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me ! :_)

Answer (score 0):

This middleware for handling your 404, should be placed after your last route. *Otherwise as per your code, all your hits will return 404*.

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Besides, your form should send POST request not GET

```
<form  action="/" method="POST">
```

Also, res.render is used to render a view. You can use res.send or res.json as you prefer.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var username=req.body.username;
  var password=req.body.password;
  res.send("the username and password you posted:" +password+username);
});
```